# Position of document in result set in Solr

Tags: java, tomcat, solr, lucene

I need to know position of the document in Solr results. Let me explain why. We want to show to user position of his item in search (so that user can buy promotion and move it up). Now I query over all pages until I find the document, but it generates a lot of calls to Solr. Is there are way to get by id and query position of the element? Preferably by list of ids so that I can query it in one go.

Sample query:

```
/search?sort=sort_time%20desc&fq=category_parent_id:2003&rows=15&q=&start=0
```

Sample document:

```
{
    sort_time: 1421747930,
    id: 146002852,
    catlevel2: "Volvo",
    catlevel1: "Auto's",
    description: "Volvo XC90",
    score: 6.4758344
}
```

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594218/solr-search-results-and-retrieving-position-of-document)? Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666521/ranking-or-position-of-a-solr-document-in-search-results)?

Comment: @mindas I have seen both of them, I was unable to extract any usable solutions from them. If you can - please, I will award you bounty right away.

Comment: Can you add a sample document in the question? More to the point are your documents ordered by a numeric field ?

Comment: How many documents are in the index?

Comment: @cheffe in total somewhere around 4 millions.

Comment: hm, your sample query is somewhat confusing. You sort by **sort_time**, so why not count all documents that have a greater/smaller sort_time?

Comment: @cheffe that is search query that is used to present data to user. I want to be able to determine document position in this query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sorting by "sort_time" which looks like a timestamp in milis.

Let's do the following: query all results that have a "sort_time" between 1421747930 and NOW with a range query. This will give you a "count" number of results even in the first resultset. If you order by "sort_time desc" your desired position is "count" as your result will be the last one in that range query. Try that same query adding a "sort_time:[1421747930 TO NOW]" for instance (this might not be the exact syntax, check it out). If you get a total of 137 results the position of 1421747930 will be 137. Myeb you need the max "sort_time" instead of NOW etc... I hope you get the idea.

Now you issue a second query with the exact id to get the rest of the data.

You get what you want with 2 queries though. I would suggest you play with the idea of ranges to get what you need.

Comment: This works perfectly, this is rather simple solution, why didn't I came up with it myself :) Awarding you a bounty with great pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

I have used below approach to pass list of id in one shot to solr search query

First process the idlist on java side and make query string something like

```
String qry = "id:1 OR id:2 OR id:6"
SolrQuery solrQry         = new SolrQuery();
solrQry.set("q", qry);

SolrServer solrServer = new HttpSolrServer(SOLR_SERVER_URL);
QueryResponse response =  solrServer.query(solrQuery);
```

Comment: This will just return 3 items and not show their position in general query

Comment: Yes, this way you can get n documents based on doc id list.  For document position from search result you can implement something like list iterator to get position of  result item

Comment: How can I by passing Ids figure out position in search?

Answer (score 0):

Position of item in search result is depends on its score which is not unique so you can't exactly retrieve item by it position in search result.
But you can limit your request and sort items by score: [CommonQueryParameters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters)